# How to split a string on a control character?

Tags: zsh, string

I know how to split a string on a printable separator character; e.g. if the separator is `,`:

```
FOO='x,y,z'
printf "%s\n" ${(s:,:)FOO}
x
y
z
```

But what if the separator is a control character, such as `\034`?  For example

```
FOO=$'x\034y\034z'
```

I've tried putting everything I can think of between the `:`'s in the `(s:...:)` qualifier, including `\034`, `$'\034'`, and several others, but nothing I've tried splits the original string.

(One solution that is not acceptable would be to perform a global substitution that replaces all occurrences of the original delimiter with, for example, `,`, and then to split the resulting string with `(s:,:)`.  The reason for ruling out such a solution is that the rational for using `$'\034' as delimiter in the first place is to reduce the chance that the delimited text would contain a delimiter.  Replacing the original delimiter with a printable one completely defeats this rationale.)

---

EDIT: regarding putting the delimiter in a variable, I tried the following test script

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

DELIM=$'\034'
FOO="x${DELIM}y${DELIM}z"

BAR=(${(ps:$DELIM:)FOO})
printf "%s\n" $BAR

BAZ=(${(ps:\034:)FOO})
printf "%s\n" $BAZ
```

The output I get is

```
x^\y^\z
x
y
z
```

(where I've used `^\` to simulate the appearance of the printed `\034` on my terminal.)

FWIW, my shell version is `zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: Work well for me with zsh 5.2

Comment: @cuonglm: oh well, I guess it's time for me to upgrade, because that's the sort of thing that *should* work. :)

Comment: You need 5.0.8 or later for using variable as delimiter. Read http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html

Comment: @cuonglm: thanks for the info; it's too bad this sort of information is not in the documentation (in the case of my shell's version that would mean an explicit mention that separators in variables are not supported)...  Then again, the business with the `p` flag *is* in the documentation, and I still managed to miss it. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `p` flag to make the following flag recognize escape sequences:

```
$ FOO=$'x\034y\034z'
$ print -rl -- ${(ps:\034:)FOO}
x
y
z
```

If you don't want to hard-code the delimiter (require version >= 5.0.8):

```
$ DELIM=$'\034'
print -rl -- ${(ps:$DELIM:)FOO}
```

Comment: Thanks!  After I posted my question it occurred to me that I could stick the separator inside a variable, say `DELIM`, and do something with `eval ... \${(s:$DELIM:)FOO}`.  This is definitely much uglier than your solution, but being able to avoid hard-coding the delimiter everywhere has its merits.

Comment: @kjo: No, you don't have to hard-code. Try `DELIM=$'\034'; print -rl -- ${(ps:$DELIM:)FOO}`

Comment: Hmmm... I tried something like that, in fact, when I first saw your answer, but for some reason it did not work.  More specifically, I had tried `SPLIT=(${(s:$DELIM:)FOO})`, but `$SPLIT` ended up with only one element (equal to the original `$FOO`).  In contrast, with the version where the delimiter is hard-coded, namely, `SPLIT=(${(s:\034:)FOO})`, `$SPLIT` is an array of several elements, as desired...

Comment: @kjo: You missed the `p` flag, didn't you?

Comment: Sorry, those were typos when I wrote the comment; I added an EDIT to my post where I show exactly the code that I tried, along with the generated output.  Again, sorry for the confusion.